# Add values of same key in a dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

My input is a list and I want to convert it into a dictionary and add all values for the same keys. like in the give example in a random list `k` has two values `1` and `3` so value of `k` in dictionary will be `{'k':4,'D':2}`. And then sort it in alphabetic order

```
Input: ['k:1','D:2','k:3']
Output {'k':4,'D':2}
```

```
dlist = ['k:1','D:2','k:3']
  
dick ={}
for x in dlist:
  key,value = x.split(':')
  dick[key] = int(value)

print(dick)
```

I have the above code but I don't know how to add two values for k?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to *actually add* the value to the pre-existing value. In your code now you just overwrite the old value with the new one.

```
dick = {}
for x in dlist:
  key, value = x.split(':')
  dick[key] = dick.get(key, 0) + int(value)
```

`dict.get(key, 0)` [gets the value of the key in the dictionary, with a default of zero](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get)

Comment: Is there any way to remove apostrophes from keys of a dict like `'d':1` but I want it like `d:1` is it possible? @Pranav Hosangadi

Comment: @stackdotpop The _apostrophes_ or _quotes_ (hyphens are `-`) indicate that it's a string. So no. Unless your dict keys are something else (like numbers)

Comment: sorry I corrected my mistake but Is there any alternative to it like change it into list or string and then striping it and it doesn't matter the output is dict object or not??@Pranav Hosangadi

Comment: @stackdotpop, I think you're getting confused by what's being printed vs what the key is. The key in the dictionary is still `d`, so when you do `x = mydict["d"]`, x will become `1`. When you _print_  it, however, to indicate that the key is a string, it prints out `{ 'd': 1 }`.

Comment: Dict keys can't be lists because keys must be immutable. If you used a tuple as the key, it would still print `{ ('d'): 1 }` because at the end of the day, the `d` is still a string and it needs a way to tell you that. @stackdotpop

Answer (score 4):

This is possible by making `dick` a `defaultdict`. So, now you can just `+=` the value.

```
from collections import defaultdict

dlist = ['k:1','D:2','k:3']
  
dick = defaultdict(int)
for x in dlist:
    key, value = x.split(':')
    dick[key] += int(value)

print(dick)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `groupby` from `itertools` to group same values and then sum.

```py
import itertools
a=['k:1','D:2','k:3']
print({k:sum([int(j[1]) for j in v]) for k,v in itertools.groupby([i.split(":") for i in sorted(a)], lambda x: x[0])})
```

**Output**

```
{'D': 2, 'k': 4}
```